# Filter an observable array

Tags: angular, rxjs

Im new with rxjs operator and i try to simplify my code.
When a state change ( currentstate ), i want to filter my list of projects with this specific state and restrict to 10 items.

Here my code :

```
    this.currentState$
      .pipe(
        take(1),
        switchMap(state => {
          this.state = state;
          return this.projects$;
        }),
        takeWhile(_ => this.alive),
        filter(projects => !!projects.length),
        map(projects => {
          console.log('------------------MAP------------');
          return projects.filter((project: Project, index: number) => project.state === this.state.id && index < this.count);
        }))
      .subscribe(projects => this.filteredProjects = projects);
```

I tried to simplofy and return an observable but it looks like the Switchmap log is called 3times and i don't understand why. Is it normal ?

Here the code :

```
    return this.currentState$
      .pipe(
        take(1),
        switchMap(state => {
          console.log('----SWITCHMAP-----');
          this.state = state;
          return this.projects$.pipe(
            filter(projects => !!projects.length),
            map(projects => projects.filter((project: Project, index: number) => project.state === this.state.id && index < this.count)));
        }));
```

Other question : I want to load more item it's possible to make it easily?
I think i need first create an observable filter by state. If the state change i have the new list.
And after each click I create an other observable with the list restrict by number of items ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution :

```
  private filterProjects() {
    return this.currentState$.pipe(
      switchMap(state => this.store.pipe(select(fromProject.getAllProjects),
        map(projects => projects.filter((project: Project) => project.state === state.id))
      )));
  }

  loadMore() {
    this.count += 10;
  }
```